# Roku:show each item's channel name under the channel logo in Grid screen

Tags: roku, brightscript

How can we display the each item's channel name in each row of the grid-screen?
I am being able to display when item is focused only but i want to display channel name when loading all the row list

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. What Scenegraph node are you using (RowList, PosterGrid, ArrayGrid, etc.)? Are you able to display the channel name on top of the poster, or on top like the Roku HomeScreen?

Comment: i am using RowList

Comment: you can see this zip file https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Playing+Videos?preview=/1608528/4259949/Simple_Grid_and_Video.zip where they have displayed in focused item logo and above logo there is channel name and description and i have use same file but i just want channel name under the channel logo  in every channel logo not in focused only but when load the app display logo channel name

Answer (score 0):

To create a custom component for each item in RowList, you would need to create a new XML file that defines the item and has a function to populate each item based on the ContentNode that is passed in. In your case, I would use a LayoutGroup Scenegraph Component to combine both an image and a text. In addition, you need to include an itemContent interface field that will be passed in when rendering the component as a Content Node. Here is example code for defining a Row Item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<component name="RowListItem" extends="Group">

<interface>
  <field id="itemContent" type="node" onChange = "showcontent"/>
</interface>

<script type="text/brightscript" >
<![CDATA[

  function init() as void
    m.itemImage = m.top.findNode("itemImage")
    m.itemText = m.top.findNode("itemText")
    m.itemRectangle = m.top.findNode("itemRectangle")
  end function
]]>
</script>

<children>
    <LayoutGroup layoutDirection="vert" vertAlignment="top" itemSpacings="20" translation="[0,0]" >
        <Rectangle
          id="itemRectangle"
          color="#A9A9A9"
          opacity="0.9"
          width="400"
          height="350"
          translation="[0,0]" >
        <Poster
          id="itemImage"
          translation="[0,0]"
          width="400"
          height="180" />
        <Label
          id="itemText"
          color="0xFFFFFF"
          horizAlign="left"
          translation="[10,200]"
          font="font:MediumSystemFont"
          width="400"
          height="65" />
        </Rectangle>
    </LayoutGroup>
</children>

</component>
```

You will also need to set up a function to assign the text and logo to each component based on the ContentNode sent through the RowList. Finally, you need to include the following field in your RowList component definition in the XML file:

```
itemComponentName="RecommendedRowListItem"
```

Hope this helps!